# Does the Compat pre/suffix has to used everywhere, in xml and code?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx

if there is for example an

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

in my layout do i then also have to reference it in the code of that type, or can i also just catch it as

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.idOfAboveCompatLayout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppCompatButton` extends from `Button`, so your `findViewById()` is fine. In general, `AppCompatSnicklefritz` extends from `Snicklefritz` (for varying values of `Snicklefritz`), so you can cast to `Snicklefritz` without problems.

Comment: first time ever hearing or reading the word `Snicklefritz` :D